# Is there a way to greatly increase Hawke's base attributes in Dragon Age 2?

Tags: dragon-age-2

After playing through Dragon Age 2 a few times, I'm looking to have some fun in the game. Basically, I want Hawke to have a normally unreachably high amount of their main stats (STR, DEX, CON, INT, WIS, CHA) to check how ludicrous my damage numbers can get. I also want to do this from the moment I reach Kirkwall.

I've already reached Kirkwall in this playthrough, but I'm not yet inside (only just came off the boat) and I've found Gibbeds savedgame editor, but I cannot seem to edit my base stats without breaking the ability to load any of my savedgames (obviously I made backups).

I'm playing the PC version downloaded from Origin and I am a rogue. I'm open to try anything that doesn't end up causing the game to crash or encounter bugs that render it unfinishable. I'm aiming to get about 175-200 of each stat, so i still got room for growth.

Comment: I just figured out why my savedgames were broken after editing them. Apparently, you cannot have 2 .das files (the savedgame file itself) in the same folder or the game can't load either of them. So saving the backup of my savedgame in the same folder as the savedgame didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable the [developer's console](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Console_%28Dragon_Age_II%29) and give yourself items and to tweak various other things.

To modify your character stats/skills, you can use a memory editor like [cheat engine](http://www.cheatengine.org/).

Comment: It mentions 2 methods of changing your stats. Supercrit prohibits picking up items on some versions, and the other option isn't permanent (only 3 minute buff). it also mentions you need to use a 3rd party mod to give yourself items. I'm looking for a permanent way that doesn't break the game, as mentioned above.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs using cheat engine seems work quite well, I just tried it and set my stat/skill points to 300 each.